# jquery if checkbox is checked, alert with result isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. It is supposed to check if a checkbox is checked, and alert "checked" if it is and "not checked" if it's not. However it keeps returning the "checked" result every time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#midmenusubmit').click(function () {
            if ($('input:c2:checked').val() != undefined) {
                alert("checked");
                //checked
            }
            else {
                alert("not checked");
                //not checked
            }

        });
    });


<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="c2" ></input>


<img src="image.png" id="midmenusubmit" />
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong, it should be `#c2` not `:c2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a more succinct way to check the state of your checkbox:

```
if ($('input#c2').is(':checked')) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use

```
$('input:c2:checked').length > 0
```

or

```
$('input:c2').is(':checked') // returns true or false
```

The .val() is looking for a value on the input element and never finds it hence it always being undefined

Comment: Almost got it - missed this important point: input:c2 is not a valid value. should be as BoltClock noted. Good point on .is() however.